# PHP Login Script - How Many Logins

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a question from a potential client (hence, no code yet) about a website they have which has a custom login script.

Basically, they have Analytics setup but it doesn't serve the purpose that they need - being  able to tell how many times a user has logged in and how frequently they do so.

What would be the best way of achieving this? I'm guessing I would need to alter the PHP login script but I'm a little confused at how best to do it. I could do a new field in the database that counts their logins but I suspect that that's not a great way of doing it, and I'm not sure how I could tell the frequency from that type of system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would really depend on their current analytics setup, and whehter you would need to track user-identifiable (i.e. you can identify the individual) data or just per-user data that is anonymous.  Storing the data in a database may, in fact, be a very good option depending on what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a user logs in you could log it in your db or to a file.  You could easily include user name, datetime, ip, user agent (all relevant data) etc.  As mentioned this will make it very easy to build a profile on the user, login times, login locations etc

Answer (score 2):

If you store the time of each attempt, you can run reports to figure out whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to implement this is a relational database.  When a user is logged in, an entry is made in a table.  When you want to find out how many times a user has logged in, a query to this table to count the entries that apply to that user.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make a new table where you store `user_id` and `timestamp` everytime the user is logging in. Using that data you can then see who, how many times and in which intervals of the day has been logged in.